Partial line coverage report with dotnet-coverage
I am working on a C# project and would like to find out which lines are "to cover" with unit tests.
I run the following commands to execute the tests and upload them to sonarqube
dotnet sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"projectname" /d:sonar.login="token" /d:sonar.host.url="http://url" /v:0 /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=coverage.xml

dotnet build path/to/project

dotnet-coverage collect 'dotnet test path/to/project/solution.sln' -f xml  -o 'coverage.xml'

dotnet sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end /d:sonar.login="token"

These command work nice in general, but I am experiencing a weird behaviour when there are no Unit Tests.
In fact, when there are none, I get this warning on dotnet-coverage:
No test is available in /path/to/test/project/bin/Debug/net6.0/testproject.Test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized. Verify that glibc (>=2.27), libxml2 and all .NET dependencies are installed.

This results in a partial report. For example, on my project it results on 1956 lines of code to cover in 27 files.
When the same steps are executed with some unit tests, it results in 3099 over 128 files.
My question is: is there any way to immediatly get a full coverage report that shows all lines needing to be covered even when there are no unit tests present?
Thank you very much in advance.
